# GoogleAPI: Gelocation - Daily Limit Exceeded on first request

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, google-api

I am working with a Ruby project to use Google's geolocation API.  When I try to use an API key I receive the following error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded",
    "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
 }
}
```

I have used the same Google project and API with success a couple of months ago but cannot seem to get it working now.

Relevant details and troubleshooting efforts:

1. The quotas page currently shows only 25 out of 100 requests used.
2. I have validated that billing is enabled.
3. I have validated that the 'Google Maps Geolocation API' is enabled in Services.
4. I have validated that the Referer on the Browser key is set to 'Any referer allowed'
5. I have issued a new Browser key, no change.
6. I have tried converted to a Server API key, no change.
7. I have destroyed the project, created a new one, enabled the Geolocation API in service, enabled billing, and issued a new key, no change.
8. I have used invalid keys, no keys, and invalid JSON and verified that the resulting error messages are appropriate.
9. I have attempted requests from a different machine with a different public IP.
10. I have used the CURL testing example at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/#sample-requests to remove my application as the source of the issue.

> curl -d @test.txt -H "Content-Type: application/json" -i
>   "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=MYAPIKEYHERE"

Any feedback on this would be appreciated.